# Use UDP with ROS2

Tags: c++, ros2

I'm a ROS2 beginner.
It seems that ROS1 was able to do UDP `ros :: TransportHints (). Unreliable ()`, but ROS2 doesn't seem to have this function.
What should I do when performing UDP connection with ROS2 C++?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems that ros2 is pretty new, maybe not everything is fully migrated at this stage. Anyway, you may be interested to ask your question in [ros answers](https://answers.ros.org/questions/) (which is a _"stack overflow like"_ specialized for ros). You might find more resources and more specific/informed answers there with the ros community.

Comment: ROS2 is built on top of DDS, a publish–subscribe middleware standard, unlike ROS1 which used a custom protocol. Using DDS is probably the biggest improvement over ROS1. DDS uses UDP as the transport layer which is unreliable by design, therefore DDS has QoS policies that add extra functionality such as "reliability". The options for this QoS policy are: "reliable" - The publisher continuously sends the message to the subscriber until the subscriber confirms receipt of the message. "besteffort" - The publisher sends the message only once, and does not confirm that the subscriber receives it.

Answer (score 3):

To use ROS2 in an UDP fashion, meaning that lost package do not matter, you have to set your topics to best effort at Blue7 mentions.

You can do this by the following piece of code:

```
static const rclcpp::QoS qos = rclcpp::QoS(1).reliability(RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT); // set QOS profile to best effort with a queu of 1
    
subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::Bool>
        ("/topic", qos, std::bind(&class::calbackFunction, this, _1));
```

Do not forget that he publisher also needs to be best effort, which can be done in the same way